# Include tags in RSS feed

Tags: feature-request, rss

Many questions are ambiguous without their corresponding tags. Could we add them to the RSS feed?

Comment: It may not be to your taste, but you can get an RSS just for certain tags.

Comment: I'd rather have the full stream, annotated. It's not a high-volume feed.

Comment: At the very least the top tag (like in the page title) would be helpful. Furthermore, there are RSS readers that can parse extended data and do interesting things with it, so having it implemented in proper `<item><category>` tags (RSS) or `<entry><category>` tags (Atom) would be ideal.

Comment: I was about to say "This might be better at Meta.SO, actually," then I went looking to see if it was already proposed. Instead I found [strong indication that new RSS/Atom features are not being considered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104673/153219). Digging into Stack2RSS (from that link), it looks like the Stack API simply doesn't expose a question's tags, making it unlikely to be an easily-implemented feature. Sadface. :(